# Can a differential equation result in a tetrational growth?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, tetration

For an ordinary differential equation
$$f(y^{(n)}(x), y^{(n-1)}(x),...,y''(x),y'(x),y(x),x) = 0$$
where $f$ can be written in a closed form using only elementary functions, is it possible for its solution $y(t)$ to grow as fast as tetration or faster?

By "written in a closed form using only elementary functions", I mean that there only finite composition of addition, multiplication, exponentiation, exponential and trigonometric functions and their inverses are used, i.e. no tricks like infinite sums.

By "growing as fast as tetration or faster", I mean that there is $k\in\mathbb N$ and $a >1$, such that
$y(x) \ge a \uparrow\uparrow \lfloor x\rfloor$ for all $x \ge k$.

Comment: What differential equation does a basic tetration function satisfy? (I mean, can we try to write it down?)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon That differential equation would trivially answer the question, finding it (if it exists at all) is the difficult part. A basic tetration is defined recursively for natural numbers by $a\uparrow\uparrow1=a$ and $a\uparrow\uparrow(n+1)=a^{a\uparrow\uparrow n}$. It is not trivial to extend the definition to real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts , I was just speculating. I will try a better attempt next time out.

Comment: Some hand waving: we can replace equation with first-order vector equation, and get $\vec y(x + h) \approx \vec y(x) + f(\vec y(x))$. As $f$ growth slower than $x \uparrow\uparrow n$, $\vec y(x)$ should grow slower than $x \uparrow\uparrow n + 1$. I am not sure if it can be done strict (or even if the initial claim is true).

Comment: Consider $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{1}{1-x}$?